# How has plain.tex been updated?

Tags: plain-tex

I've noticed that on CTAN there is a new version of the file `plain.tex`, dating 2021-01-17.  But nowehere I see what the changes are.  What has changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ diff  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex .
228c228
< \outer\def\newmuskip{\alloc@3\muskip\muskipdef\@cclvi}
---
> \outer\def\newmuskip{\alloc@3\muskip\muskipdef\@cclv}
232c232
< \outer\def\newtoks{\alloc@5\toks\toksdef\@cclvi}
---
> \outer\def\newtoks{\alloc@5\toks\toksdef\@cclv}
1241c1241
< \def\fmtname{plain}\def\fmtversion{3.141592653} % identifies the current format
---
> \def\fmtname{plain}\def\fmtversion{3.1415926535} % identifies the current format
```

So you can allocate one less muskip and one less toks registers.

Campa cites the official documentation here:

Knuth's explanation can be found in https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb42-1/tb130knuth-tuneup21.pdf

> Plain TEX has also changed in a minor way, for consistency: It now
> ensures that `\muskip255` and `\toks255` are available as “scratch
> registers” (never allocated by `\newmuskip` or `\newtoks`). The new
> incarnation defines `\fmtversion` as 3.1415926535.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? One can allocate one muskip and one toks register *less* than before.

Comment: @egreg clearly I can't read Roman: I'm not as old or as Italian as you... I'll fix thanks

Comment: @campa thanks..